# CockroachDB username in NodeJS (pg) connection string?

Tags: jdbc, cockroachdb

When I started my cluster, it didn't require that I specify a username, so I'm not sure what I should use to connect.

Here's the connection string I'm trying to use with `pg`:

```
var config = {
  user: '???',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'mydb',
  port: 26257
};
```

Answer (score 2):

CockroachDB's default user is called `root`.

So, in your code example above, you'd use this:

```
var config = {
  user: 'root',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'mydb',
  port: 26257
};
```

You *can* also create your own users using [`cockroach user set`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/create-and-manage-users.html), and those users would also need certificates if you want to use them in a secure/production environment.